# How to use ffill in a Pandas df selectively, depending on the row data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to fill columns in a Pandas df with the preceding entry, however not all cells in that column require that entry - and in fact require a different entry. For example:

original df:

```
    OAS     CLASS2  CLASS3  CLASS4  Ticker
0   240.59  NaN     NaN     NaN     Total
1   269.72  Fins    NaN     NaN     Fins
2   251.88  Fins    Banking Banking Banking
3   234.44  Fins    NaN     NaN     ACAFP
4   195.80  Fins    NaN     NaN     ACHMEA
5   288.63  Fins    Insur   NaN     Insur
6   313.79  Fins    Insur   Life    Life
7   425.27  Fins    Insur   Life    ACAFP
8   304.39  Fins    NaN     NaN     AEGON
```

code:

```
df2 = df.fillna(method='ffill')
df2

    OAS     CLASS2  CLASS3  CLASS4  Ticker
0   240.59  NaN     NaN     NaN     Total
1   269.72  Fins    NaN     NaN     Fins
2   251.88  Fins    Banking Banking Banking
3   234.44  Fins    Banking Banking ACAFP
4   195.80  Fins    Banking Banking ACHMEA
5   288.63  Fins    Insur   Banking Insur
6   313.79  Fins    Insur   Life    Life
7   425.27  Fins    Insur   Life    ACAFP
8   304.39  Fins    Insur   Life    AEGON
```

The issue is in row 5 where the CLASS4 column cell now says Banking instead of NaN but should say 'Insur' as per the adjacent columns to the left and right. I realise my code hasn't attempted to rectify the issue at all but I just wouldn't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ffill` method of `fillna()` propagates the **last** observed non-null value forward until another non-null value is encountered.

So, what is happening in your case is that, in CLASS4 the value **Banking** is observed and is propagated to all the NaN values until another non-null value is encountered in this column.

So, in order to fill the NaN with the values from left, you have to provide `axis=1` parameter to your `fillna()` method.

Doing the following:

```
df2 = df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1)
df2
```

Will result into something like this:

```
0   0   240.59  240.59  240.59  240.59  Total
1   1   269.72  Fins    Fins    Fins    Fins
2   2   251.88  Fins    Banking Banking Banking
3   3   234.44  Fins    Fins    Fins    ACAFP
4   4   195.8   Fins    Fins    Fins    ACHMEA
5   5   288.63  Fins    Insur   Insur   Insur
6   6   313.79  Fins    Insur   Life    Life
7   7   425.27  Fins    Insur   Life    ACAFP
8   8   304.39  Fins    Fins    Fins    AEGON
```

Comment: Is there any way to prevent the first row from being filled in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Just provide `axis=0` inside `fillna()`